# VS 2010 Report Viewer Cannot Access Nested Collections, Anyone?

Tags: c#, .net, list, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have gone through all the walk through on MSDN as usual they are worthless - extremely limited.

If I make the internal object in my class a single class I can display the information, but as soon as I convert it to a list of objects ( a collection ) I get the #Error in the display.

Here is an updated example.

For an example I have a Person object that can have one or more phone numbers ( list of numbers ) and I cannot find a way to access the phone numbers.

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    private readonly List<PhoneNumber> _numbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(int id, string name, string address, decimal salary)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    public void AddNumber(PhoneNumber number)
    {
        _numbers.Add(number);            
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get { return _numbers; } }       

}

[Serializable]
public class PhoneNumber
{
    public PhoneNumber()
    {
    }

    public PhoneNumber(int id, string areaCode, string phone)
    {
        AreaCode = areaCode;
        Id = id;
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I then populate the collections.

```
    var persons = new List<Person>();

    var t = new Person(1, "Mike", "5150 Nuts", 125);

    t.AddNumber(new PhoneNumber(1, "425", "455"));
    t.AddNumber(new PhoneNumber(1, "425", "450"));

    persons.Add(t);

    t = new Person(2, "Tom", "1055 MS HAS NO DOCUMENTATION AS USUAL!", 1245);

    t.AddNumber(new PhoneNumber(2, "TYPICAL", "OF-THEM"));
    t.AddNumber(new PhoneNumber(2, "ANY", "ONE???"));

    persons.Add(t);
```

I then assign everything to the report.

```
    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "..\\..\\Report1.rdlc";
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Person",persons));
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

In the report it displays the people will display without issue as I add the text boxes to a list and then group the list by Id.  When I try to display the phone numbers, I get the #ERROR message, and for the life of me I cannot seem to find a way to display the list of numbers that are assigned to a person.

If I change the object from `List<PhoneNumber>` within the person class to `PhoneNumber` I can access it, but when trying to display a `List<PhoneNumber>` I cant.

I need to be ale to display `List<of objects>` within an Class Item.

Comment: How is the report formatted? It looks to me like you just need to group the report by Name, with the numbers making up the detail.

Comment: The problem I have is that I cant even get to the phone-numbers at all.  All that shows when I create the object is Name and Address in the actual report designer.  I am using VS2010 and I cannot for the life of me get access to the phone numbers.  I really need the ability to access nested list.  any idea?

Comment: What made you think this would work? Have you ever seen an example? Notice that most reporting services data sources are, effectively, flat.

Comment: @John, often when RDLC is demo'd they (Microsoft) often 'blow past' the mechanics of sub reports only showing that it is 'possible'...but not how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested collection must be displayed as a subreport where the nested collection is an separate data source. You must bind the event [**LocalReport.SubreportProcessing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx) to a handler that will filter and bind the datasource (PhoneNumbers) to the subreport as a seperate report data source. The example at the link provided should get you where you need to go.